# Taylor series of $\sin(x+1)+\cos(x-1)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I want to find the Taylor series of $f(x)=\sin(x+1)+\cos(x-1)$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

We know the Taylor of $\sin(x)$ for $x_0=0$, so can I simply say that $\sin(x+1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(x+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}~$ at $x_0=0$?

What should I do for $f$ for an unknown $x_0$?

Thanks!

Comment: Write it as $\sin((x-x_0)+(x_0+1))+\cos((x-x_0)+(x_0-1))$ and break up the sine and cosine  using the formulas for the sum of two angles. After than you will get an expression that consists of $\sin(x-x_0)$ and $\cos(x-x_0)$ multiplied by some constants (that depend on $x_0$ but not on $x$). These, two you expand using the series that you know for $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Another approach is compute successive derivatives and evaluate them at $x_0$. Just like the derivatives of sine and cosine repeat, so will be the derivatives of your function. Then you evaluate them at $x=x_0$ and write down $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{f^{(n)(x_0)}}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$.

Comment: Thank you, will try!

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(x+1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ is *not* the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x+1)$ around $x=0$. It is the expansion around $x+1=0$. Or $x=-1$ if you prefer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for the answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing all already said in comments, around $x=x_0$, you should have for

$$f(x)=\sin(x+1)+\cos(x-1)$$
$$f(x)=(\sin(1)+\cos(1)) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin \left(x_0+n\frac{\pi  }{2}\right)+\cos \left(x_0+n\frac{\pi  }{2}\right)}{n!}\,(x-x_0)^n$$

You could even make it more general for
$$g(x)=a \sin (x+b)+c \cos (x+d)$$ and obtain
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a \sin \left(x_0+b+\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)+c \cos \left(x_0+d+\frac{\pi 
   n}{2}\right)}{n!}\,(x-x_0)^n$$

Comment: Thank you Claude! Can you please explain where the $n \frac{\pi}{2}$ came from? Thanks!

Comment: @CalculusLover. Pattern recognition is you want a nice looking word ! In fact, habit since I felt in love with Taylor (series !) 64+ years ago ! Chhers :-)

Comment: Amazing to hear that! I followed the pattern, and got for $\sin(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
(-1)^{n/2}\sin(x_0) & n=2k\\ 
 (-1)^{(n-1)/2}\sin(x_0+\frac{\pi}{2})& n=2k-1 
\end{matrix}\right.$  I just need to understand the final stage. Can you help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$f(x_0+h) = \sin(x_0+h+1)+\cos(x_0+h-1).$$

Then use trigonometric identities like

$$\sin(x_0+h+1) = \cos (x_0+1) \sin h + \cos h \sin (x_0+1)$$

to come back to Taylor series expansion of $\sin h$ and $\cos h$ around zero that you know.

Comment: Thank you. Why can I use $f(x_0+h)$? How is it connect to $f(x)$?

Comment: When you use Taylor expansion you can either write $f(x_0+h) = f(x_0) + f^\prime(x_0)h+ \dots$ or $f(x) = f(x_0) + f^\prime(x_0)(x-x_0)+ \dots$. I'm using first notation in my answer.

Comment: Oh, we didn't learn this, so I can't use it I'm afraid :(

Comment: Just replace $h$ with $x-x_0$ in what I wrote… and you’ll get what you learnt.

Comment: Alright cool! How can I expand it for a general $x_0$ ?

Comment: It’s almost done as you know the expansion of $\cos x, \sin x$ at $0$. Just use that to expand $\sin h , \cos h$ and replace $h$ with $x-x_0$.

Comment: So for $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ (ignoring the constants) I got $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n ((x-x_0)^{2n+1}+(2n+1)(x-x_0)^{2n})}{(2n+1)!}$, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The successive derivatives at $x_0$ are

$$\ \ \ \sin(x_0+1)+\cos(x_0-1),
\\\ \ \ \cos(x_0+1)-\sin(x_0-1),
\\-\sin(x_0+1)-\cos(x_0-1),
\\-\cos(x_0+1)+\sin(x_0-1),$$

and so on periodically.

Hence you can express the Taylor series as four sums of powers of $(x-x_0)$,
grouping the powers with the same modulo $4$.

Comment: Thanks Yves! If I write it as 4 sums, I will change the sum order which can cause problems on infinite sum, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @CalculusLover: the idea was to group the expressions of the terms, non need to reorder. But as the sum is absolutely convergent, no problem to reorder.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By basic trig identities, it can be easily showed that:
$$\sin\left(x+1\right)+\cos\left(x-1\right)=\left(\sin1+\cos1\right)\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)$$

Comment: Cool, and then to find the Taylor series around a general $x_0$?

Comment: Sure, it should be easier since you should be familiar with those taylor series. remember that $\cos1+\sin1$ is just a scalar.

Comment: So for $\sin$ for example we get $T_n(x)=\sin(x_0)+\cos(x_0)(x-x_0)-\frac{\sin(x_0)(x-x_0)^2}{2!}-\frac{\cos(x_0)(x-x_0)^3}{3!}+...$, am I correct?

Comment: Or maybe, around $x_0$ we get $\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(x+x_0)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}~$ ?